# Pulling console.log data into html

Tags: javascript, html, console.log

Through JavaScript, I have retrieved weather data that shows in my console.log. How do I initiate the retrieval of this data into my html file?

console.log shows this:

{coord: {…}, weather: Array(2), base: 'stations', main: {…}, visibility: 805, …}
base
:
"stations"
clouds
:
{all: 100}
cod
:
200
coord
:
{lon: -84.388, lat: 33.749}
dt
:
1682616284
id
:
4180439
main
:
feels_like
:
287.33
humidity
:
89
pressure
:
1015
temp
:
287.51
temp_max
:
288.48
temp_min
:
286.18
[[Prototype]]
:
Object
name
:
"Atlanta"
rain
:
{1h: 3.16}

I want to retrieve this information into this html:

```
        <div class="topMiddle-row" id="cityDetails">
                     <div class="cityName">City</div>
                     <p class="temp">temp</p>
                     <p class="hum">hum</p>
                     <p class="wind">wind</p>
                     <p class="cloud">cloud</p>                         
                     <p class="Rain">uv</p>
                </div>

This is my current JavaScript:
function currentCondtions(cityDetails) {
     const weatherData = {
          coord: {},
          weather: Array(1),
          base: 'stations',
          main: {},
          visibility: 3219,
          clouds: {all: 100}};
const cityDetailsDiv = document.querySelector('#cityDetails');
const cldsTxtNode = document.createTextNode(`Clouds: 
${cloudsData.clouds.all}%`);
cityDetailsDiv.appendChild(cldsTxtNode);
```

Comment: show the code where you are requesting it? do you have a ui framework?

Comment: There are any number of ways to insert data into the DOM; it might be valuable to search for something like "update DOM dynamically" or something. There are a ton of libraries and frameworks that can "help" with this, or it can be done w/ vanilla JS.

Comment: It's not clear what the actual problem you're having is; if you can retrieve the data in JS *(presumably through a function called in a `<script>` tag)* then picking out parts of that data looks like `theData.temp`, and you can update the DOM by getting the target element and setting its text.

Comment: I am an absolute beginner to JS and am having a very hard time getting my head around this coding. I appreciate everyone's feedback thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply using the date you're displaying in the `console.log` and put it (if possible) in the `innerHTML` of your paragraphs. However, first I would change the classes name to be ids if they're the only one present in the page.

After, you can do it like this in JS:

```js
document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = the data you extracted;
```

And repeat the process for all the data you need to show!